# How to update the settings.js in node-red/node-red-docker image when deployed with resin.io?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, node-red

I am using a Dockerfile with below contents which I deploy using [resin.io](http://resin.io) on a raspberry pi.

```
FROM nodered/node-red-docker:rpi-v8
USER root
RUN sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep'  $(eval readlink -f `which node`)
USER node-red
```

I would also like to update the `settings.js` that is used by Node-RED but I do not know how I can do this.

I have created a file `settings.js` and added the following line to my Dockerfile just after the RUN command ... which did build and got deployed by [resin.io](http://resin.io) without any errors.

```
COPY settings.js /data/
```

... but when checking the `/data/` folder I see that the `settings.js` is not updated.  I can still see the old `settings.js` which was automatically created by a previous deployment and start of the container.

FYI the contents of the `/data` folder of my container:

```
node-red@997563c:~$ ls -l /data
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 node-red node-red  283 Oct 28 08:57 flows.json
drwxr-xr-x 3 node-red node-red 4096 Oct 27 10:44 lib
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root     4096 Oct 26 22:27 node-red
-rw-r--r-- 1 node-red node-red  120 Oct 27 16:44 package.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 node-red node-red 8091 Oct 27 10:44 settings.js
node-red@997563c:~$
```

FYI here below the container log file covering the start of Node-RED application:

```
28.10.18 11:18:03 (+0100) Starting service 'main sha256:472f9797c9288bc3d5a9147597fd33fb982ab34f4eb0e467f70842f05a421f3b'
28.10.18 11:18:04 (+0100)  main  mount: only root can use "--types" option
28.10.18 11:18:04 (+0100)  main  mount: only root can use "--move" option
28.10.18 11:18:04 (+0100)  main  mount: only root can use "--move" option
28.10.18 11:18:04 (+0100)  main  mount: only root can use "--move" option
28.10.18 11:18:04 (+0100)  main  mount: only root can use "--move" option
28.10.18 11:18:04 (+0100)  main  umount: /dev: umount failed: Operation not permitted
28.10.18 11:18:04 (+0100)  main  mount: only root can use "--move" option
28.10.18 11:18:04 (+0100)  main  ln: cannot remove ‘/dev/ptmx’: Permission denied
28.10.18 11:18:04 (+0100)  main  mount: only root can use "--types" option
28.10.18 11:18:04 (+0100)  main  /sbin/udevd
28.10.18 11:18:04 (+0100) Started service 'main sha256:472f9797c9288bc3d5a9147597fd33fb982ab34f4eb0e467f70842f05a421f3b'
28.10.18 11:18:05 (+0100)  main  npm info it worked if it ends with ok
28.10.18 11:18:05 (+0100)  main  npm info using npm@5.0.3
28.10.18 11:18:05 (+0100)  main  npm info using node@v8.1.3
npm info lifecycle node-red-docker@1.0.0~prestart: node-red-docker@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle node-red-docker@1.0.0~start: node-red-docker@1.0.0
28.10.18 11:18:05 (+0100)  main
28.10.18 11:18:05 (+0100)  main  > node-red-docker@1.0.0 start /usr/src/node-red
28.10.18 11:18:05 (+0100)  main  > node $NODE_OPTIONS node_modules/node-red/red.js -v $FLOWS "--userDir" "/data"
28.10.18 11:18:05 (+0100)  main
28.10.18 11:18:08 (+0100)  main  28 Oct 10:18:08 - [info]
28.10.18 11:18:08 (+0100)  main
28.10.18 11:18:08 (+0100)  main  Welcome to Node-RED
28.10.18 11:18:08 (+0100)  main  ===================
28.10.18 11:18:08 (+0100)  main
28.10.18 11:18:08 (+0100)  main  28 Oct 10:18:08 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.19.4
28.10.18 11:18:08 (+0100)  main  28 Oct 10:18:08 - [info] Node.js  version: v8.1.3
28.10.18 11:18:08 (+0100)  main  28 Oct 10:18:08 - [info] Linux 4.14.39 arm LE
28.10.18 11:18:09 (+0100)  main  28 Oct 10:18:09 - [info] Loading palette nodes
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  28 Oct 10:18:12 - [info] Settings file  : /data/settings.js
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  28 Oct 10:18:12 - [info] Context store  : 'default' [module=memory]
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  28 Oct 10:18:12 - [info] User directory : /data
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  28 Oct 10:18:12 - [warn] Projects disabled : editorTheme.projects.enabled=false
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  28 Oct 10:18:12 - [info] Flows file     : /data/flows.json
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  28 Oct 10:18:12 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:80/
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  28 Oct 10:18:12 - [warn]
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  Your flow credentials file is encrypted using a system-generated key.
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  If the system-generated key is lost for any reason, your credentials
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  file will not be recoverable, you will have to delete it and re-enter
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  your credentials.
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  You should set your own key using the 'credentialSecret' option in
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  your settings file. Node-RED will then re-encrypt your credentials
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  file using your chosen key the next time you deploy a change.
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  28 Oct 10:18:12 - [info] Starting flows
28.10.18 11:18:12 (+0100)  main  28 Oct 10:18:12 - [info] Started flows
```

FYI the `df` output of my docker container:

```
node-red@997563c:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
none             6794760 748316   5677608  12% /
tmpfs              65536      0     65536   0% /dev
/dev/mmcblk0p6   6794760 748316   5677608  12% /data
none              306201 245637     40494  86% /lib/modules
tmpfs             499556      0    499556   0% /tmp/resin
shm                65536      0     65536   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             499556  10024    489532   3% /host/run/dbus
node-red@997563c:~$
```

**1st Update (2018-10-28):**

Following 2 links describe how a `settings.js` is also provided as part of the Docker build scripts for node-RED.  So it is technically possible but currently I don't know how I can do this with the official [nodered/node-red-docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/nodered/node-red-docker/) repository

1. https://github.com/resin-io-projects/balena-node-red
2. https://medium.com/@knolleary/deploying-node-red-applications-to-devices-using-resin-io-58d2042cdb0c

Comment: `/data/ is most likely being mounted as an external volume

Comment: Could you add your `docker run` command?

Comment: @bluescores I am using http://resin.io.  So the build and deploy is triggered through the command `git push resin master`.  So the actual build and deploy is done by resin.io

Comment: @hardilb - I have added the `df` output of my container at the end of my question.  So it seems you are right about that.

Comment: FYI I added the section **1st Update (2018-10-28):**  at the end of the question.

Comment: As further analysis revealed that this problem is specific due to the resin.io deployment, I have added **"when deployed with resin.io"** to the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ROOT CAUSE:**

This problem is actually due to the fact that [resin.io](http://resin.io) is using the `/data` folder for persistent storage and files can only be copied to this folder the first time the container is created for that device.  So subsequent deployments of the container won't change the contents of the `/data` folder.

This is also described in https://docs.resin.io/learn/develop/runtime/#persistent-storage.  The relevant part is copied pasted below:

> **Persistent Storage**
>
> If you have data or configurations that you would like to persist through application and host OS updates, you have the option to keep them in persistent storage. Persistent storage is a good place to write system logs and other application data that should remain untouched even as your code changes
>
> ...
>
> **resinOS v2.12.0 and above**
>
> Beginning with resinOS v2.12.0, persistent
>   storage is handled through **named volumes**. The behavior is much the
>   same as persistent storage on older host OS versions. In fact, for
>   single-container applications, the default docker-compose.yml sets up
>   a resin-data named volume that links to a `/data` directory in the
>   container. The only difference between this and earlier versions is
>   that accessing this data via the host OS is done at
>   /var/lib/docker/volumes/_resin-data/_data, rather than the
>   /mnt/data/resin-data/ location used with earlier host OS
>   versions.
>
> Named volumes can be given arbitrary names and can be linked to a
>   directory in one or more containers. As long as every release of the
>   application includes a docker-compose.yml and the volume name does not
>   change, the data in the volume will persist across updates.
>
> When using named volumes, note that:
>
> *If a device is moved to a new application, the old `/data` folder will
>   be automatically purged. **During the build process, data added to a
>   container directory that is configured to link to a named volume will
>   be copied to the volume the first time it's created on the device**.*

**SOLUTION:**

In order to assure that the following instruction in the Dockerfile is effectively executed:

```
COPY settings.js /data/
```

you must execute following steps in your [resin.io](http://resin.io) dashboard.

1. Create a dummy application
2. move the device to the dummy application
3. move the device back to the original application

Step 2 will assure that the `/data` folder becomes completely wiped.

Step 3 will assure that the `settings.js` become effectively copied to the `/data` folder as it is the first time the image becomes deployed on that device.

FYI: The URL https://docs.resin.io/learn/manage/actions/#move-to-another-application describes the action **move to another application**.

On that page you can also find following statement:

> **Warning:** For devices running resinOS version 2.12.0 and above, data in
>   persistent storage (named volumes) is automatically purged when a
>   device is moved to a new application.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so the problem will be that `/data' is being mounted over the top of what ever is in the docker image.

The content of `/data` will have been laid down by a previous version of the docker image you've pushed to your resin.io device.

I can see 2 options:

1. Wipe out the whole image and start again. This only works because you are sill "playing". It would not be possible in a production setting.
2. Log into the container and edit/replace `settings.js` and restart

Comment: With option 1: do you mean that I have to burn the SD card again and start all over (https://docs.resin.io/learn/getting-started/raspberrypi3/nodejs/) ?

Comment: Yes, it's the quickest option.

Comment: OK, I slowly start to understand the problem. See also section persistent storage https://docs.resin.io/learn/develop/runtime/ . So this section says `During the build process, data added to a container directory that is configured to link to a named volume will be copied to the volume the first time it's created on the device.`

Comment: Instead of starting all over there is a much simpler solution: 
1. create a dummy application in resin.io
2. move the device to the dummy application.
3. move the device back to the original application.
Step 2 will wipe out the /data folder and step 3 will redeploy again the docker image but as it is the first time deployment it will effectively copy the settings.js to the /data/ folder (see also https://docs.resin.io/learn/manage/actions/ and https://docs.resin.io/learn/develop/runtime/#persistent-storage)